# changing multiple columns based on other columns conditions

Tags: python, pandas

```
A    B  C   D   E   F    G   H  I   J
1   22  2   7   8   1   22  2   7   8
1   71  5   53  50  1   71  5   5   5
0   3   6   2   2   0   4   6   2   2
1   61  51  3   50  1   61  5   3   2
0   52  2   2   4   0   6   2   2   4
1   2   1   51  4   1   41  1   5   4
0   1   4   2   4   0   40  4   2   4
0   50  5   2   7   0   50  5   2   7
```

---

Let say I have above dataframe
I want to change the values of columns F to I to 55, if column B  == 51 or 52, 50. I want to repeat this for other columns like C, E. this the code I wrote the following  in pandas.

```
df.loc[(df['B'] == 50) | (df['B'] == 51) | df['B'] == 50) | (df['C'] == 51), ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I' ]] = 55
```

it's not working.

Comment: this might be due to pandas creating views or copies of the initial dataframe. Thus you are not modifying your df as you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iiuc you mean sth like this :

```
df.loc[df['B'].isin([50, 51, 52]) | df['C'].isin([50, 51, 52]), ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I']] = 55
```

**Edit:**

For a longer list of lookup columns you could use

```
luc = ['B', 'C', 'E', 'F']
df.loc[df[luc].isin([50, 51, 52]).any(axis=1), ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I']] = 55
```

*(thanks @jezrael for pointing out the direct accessible method `any`)*

or

```
df.loc[np.any(df[luc].isin([50, 51, 52]), axis=1), ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I']] = 55
```

Comment: I have hundreds of columns to change 
is there way to do it like this df.loc[df['B', 'C, 'E', 'F'].isin([50, 51, 52]), ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'X', 'Y', 'W', 'Z']  = 51

Comment: `.apply(any, axis=1)` should be changed to `.any(axis=1)`

Comment: untested, only idea

Comment: I asked a wrong question, I want to check those columns: let say B, C, D. if the column value is equal to 50, 51, 52..... change it to 55. 
but this one df.loc[df['B', 'C, 'E', 'F'].isin([50, 51, 52]), ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'X', 'Y', 'W', 'Z'] = 55 change the entire ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'X', 'Y', 'W', 'Z'] values to 55.

Comment: Please be precise: assumed talking about your example looking only at B, C and D: do you want to change the value of _all_ three columns  if only _one_ is in [50, 51, 52] or do you just want to change the value in the very column where the matching value was found...? Or what?

Comment: Btw @jezrael thanks for the hint. Didn't test either,  but the docs show it clearly https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html

Comment: I want to go through certain columns and look whether that column B "OR" C value is [50 or 51 or 52] and change columns B "AND" C to 55.
I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Yes, that looks clear enough. That is exactly what the given command does except that lookup columns and change columns now are the same. Please understand, that the first list of columns is the or-combined lookup list and the second list defines in which columns you want to change the values (to 55, in your case). So if these two lists are both `['B', 'C']`, you'll get what you described in your last comment.

Comment: So right now what is the final command that I need to run. Would you please write the final command?

Comment: `col = ['B', 'C']` 
`df.loc[df[col].isin([50, 51, 52]).any(axis=1), col] = 55`